# how to create search filter in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have a website, a real estate website and I need to have a search filter, so my client can easily identify what they want or what expected budget they can! I have see this website showing same way to implement [click here](http://www.davaopropertyfinder.com/#property-search-8).

can somebody guide me what should do to make this. 
If you can suggest a tutorial I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To pull it off you need some good understanding of [The Loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and how to create personalized queries with WP_query

In a nutshell, the page you provided has its real estate logic in a custom post type named "Listings" and some tags such as "bedroom" and "price".

I am not allowed to post more than 1 hyperlink, so please use google and search the words in bold style.

**A page template**  performs a query with the desired filters, such as "3 Bedrooms" and "200000 $", and displays the results in several rows.

**A custom post type and tags,** since the listing will not automagically appear in your site's backend....

If you ask me, wordpress isn't suited for this kind of features.
I say this beacause you will often need custom plugins such as advanced custom fields, to accomplish trivial tasks like this one...
It will ultimately be a stressful situation for you.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for the tips, I have little understanding in wordpress backend like adding `custom post type` using `advanced custom fields` plugin. i will try what you suggest.